# ASP.NET TreeView and loading data on demand

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, treeview

Is there a way to force `TreeView` to load data on demand? In the other hand `TreeView` must load data only when a node is to be expanded. `TreeView` is binded to a collection of data that is implementing `IHierarchyData`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Three steps to do the trick:

1 - Set the [TreeView.ExpandDepth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.expanddepth.aspx) to *0*. This eliminates the expansion of the added `TreeNode` objects in the `TreeView` and shows the expansion symbol **[+]** next to each `TreeNode` that has the `TreeNode.PopulateOnDemand` property set to *true*.

2- Set the [TreeNode.PopulateOnDemand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treenode.populateondemand.aspx) to *True* for each *branch* `TreeNode`. When the `TreeNode.ChildNodes` collection is *empty*, the expansion symbol **[+]** will be showed only next to `TreeNode` objects that has `TreeNode.PopulateOnDemand` property set to *true*.

3- Handle the [TreeView.TreeNodePopulate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.treenodepopulate.aspx) event to poulate branch nodes on expansion. This event will be fired when a `TreeNode` - with the `TreeNode.PopulateOnDemand` set to *true* - has been expanded right before the `TreeView.TreeNodeExpanded` event gets fired.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just populate your tree based on the different events available instead of loading your whole tree at once