# ASP.NET TreeView + AJAX

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have a treeview I'm using to display a directory structure. I am trying to reduce load times by loading sub nodes on node expansion. Is there a way to do this?

Below is the code I'm currently using to populate the treeview:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    BuildTree(Request.QueryString["path"]);
}
private void BuildTree(string dirPath)
{
    //get root directory
    System.IO.DirectoryInfo rootDir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(dirPath);

    //create and add the root node to the tree view
    TreeNode rootNode = new TreeNode(rootDir.Name, rootDir.FullName);
    TreeView1.Nodes.Add(rootNode);

    //begin recursively traversing the directory structure
    TraverseTree(rootDir, rootNode);
}
private void TraverseTree(System.IO.DirectoryInfo currentDir, TreeNode currentNode)
{
    //loop through each sub-directory in the current one
    foreach (System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir in currentDir.GetDirectories())
    {
            //create node and add to the tree view
            TreeNode node = new TreeNode(dir.Name, dir.FullName);
            currentNode.ChildNodes.Add(node);

            //recursively call same method to go down the next level of the tree
            TraverseTree(dir, node);
    }

    foreach (System.IO.FileInfo file in currentDir.GetFiles())
    {
        TreeNode node = new TreeNode(file.Name, file.FullName);
        currentNode.ChildNodes.Add(node);
    }
}
```

Comment: @RenanMalkeStigliani Can you elaborate?

Comment: Your question is too much abstract, provide more details, like any framework JavaScript you are currently using to load the tree view; the tree view code, and the amount of items do you got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For loading the nodes on demand, meaning that the children of a node will be loaded only when the parent node is expanded. Do the following steps:

1 - Set the [TreeView.ExpandDepth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.expanddepth.aspx) to *0*. This eliminates the expansion of the added `TreeNode` objects in the `TreeView` and shows the expansion symbol **[+]** next to each `TreeNode` that has the `TreeNode.PopulateOnDemand` property set to *true*.

2- Set the [TreeNode.PopulateOnDemand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treenode.populateondemand.aspx) to *True* for each *branch* `TreeNode`. When the `TreeNode.ChildNodes` collection is *empty*, the expansion symbol **[+]** will be showed only next to `TreeNode` objects that has `TreeNode.PopulateOnDemand` property set to *true*.

3- Handle the [TreeView.TreeNodePopulate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.treenodepopulate.aspx) event to poulate branch nodes on expansion. This event will be fired when a `TreeNode` - with the `TreeNode.PopulateOnDemand` set to *true* - has been expanded right before the `TreeView.TreeNodeExpanded` event gets fired.

Source: [ASP.NET TreeView and loading data on demand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839862/asp-net-treeview-and-loading-data-on-demand)